# Matches of array indexs Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I have a multidimensional array q with n rows and a another multidimensional array q2 with n rows. Those arrays contain the same rows but in a different order. How can I get a list/array of matches of the 2 arrays? Example below:

```
q=array([a,b,c,d],  #row 1
        [e,f,g,h],  #row 2
        [i,l,m,n])  #row 3

q2=array([e,f,g,h], #row 2
         [a,b,c,d], #row 1
         [i,l,m,n]) #row 3

q_index=[1,2,3]
q2_index=? #I know is [2,1,3] but I can I get it?
```

I need to create the q list/array of index and the associated q2 list/array list of index.
Thank you

Comment: Please post the expected output as well.

Comment: I need the q2_index list/array ty @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: What are a, b, c...? Numbers, strings?

Comment: float numbers @thf435

Comment: So to clarify, q2_index ought to be [2,1,3]?

Comment: yes I need [2,1,3] @rpedroso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `q` to a dictionary first, convert the items to tuples first to use them as keys and use index as values.

```
>>> q = [['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','g','h'], ['i','l','m','n']]
>>> q2 = [['e','f','g','h'], ['a','b','c','d'], ['i','l','m','n']]
>>> q_dict = {tuple(x):i for i, x in enumerate(q, 1)}
>>> [q_dict[tuple(item)] for item in q2]
[2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: If the OP actually needs `q_index` to be possibly different from `[1..n]` this won't work. He is, however, not exactly clear about that...

Comment: @user3250719 Can you post the exact traceback? Note that you've a typo in your post, `m,m` is repeated twice. I fixed that before posting this.

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-09f9852414bb> in <module>()
----> 1 [q_dict[tuple(item)] for item in q2]

Comment: @user3250719 Full traceback please, `KeyError` also returns the key on which the error is being raised.

Comment: KeyError: (2.0, 254.0, 0.007874015748031496, 6.0)

Comment: Works for me. The input probably is faulty. Might even be ugly floating point errors. If the numbers are results of calculations they might differ slightly, thereby being another a key.

Comment: @user3250719 Ah! okay, can you post real examples in the question body? Because I am not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: It's huge I've got 1000 rows I can't post them.

Comment: @user3250719 :) May be a subset of them, by the do you've any row in `q` that is not present in `q2`?

Comment: @user3250719 You might want to paste them on pastebin.com and link them here... Also look at my updated answer, it might fix your problem.

Comment: @user3250719 Looks like a floating point precision issue then.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary if I print q_dict I've got the list but with that error is the q_dict a true result? I want to know because I can't verify

Comment: @user3250719 I am not sure what you meant by true result here. `q_dict` is a Python dictionary that is used to store key, value pairs. In this particular case the the items from the arrays are keys and their indices are the values.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I want to know if the matches are properly done. Maybe I have to round the float numbers of the arrays. What do you think?

Comment: @user3250719 Yes, try rounding them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, but please note that it has quadratic runtime. Polynomial is the best we will get given your current data structure. And first converting it to a different data structure might be unefficient for small `n`s. It will depend on the size of `n` if this is faster or something using hashtables. Given that the values in the arrays are float, you have to especially careful:

```
def compFloatLists(l1, l2, epsilon=0.0001):
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return False
    for e1, e2 in zip(l1, l2):
        if abs(e1-e2) > epsilon:
            return False
    return True

q2_index = []
for e1 in q2:
    for i, e2 in enumerate(q1):
        if compFloatLists(e1, e2):
            q2_index.append(q_index[i])
            break
```

As a unrelated side note: You might want to rename `q_index` to `q_indices`, which makes your code a little easier to comprehend IMHO.

Comment: Don't I need to print the q1_indices before? How? Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to print them? In this code your objective is to get the `q2_indices`. I assume of course that `q_indices` are defined before this code is run.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't mean that. I need to create also the q_index list

Comment: in q2_index I've only [1,2]

Comment: Weird, it works for me. In this case we will need more detailed examples from your use case to properly solve the problem. But I'll first get some quality sleep ;)